# Markdown Template does not render HTML Correctly

Tags: django, markdown, django-template-filters

I have created a Markdown Filter in my Django Website. I have used the library markdown2.

Though the HTML does render, it does not render it entirely.
The Code and Syntax Highlights, URLs and Lists do not render properly.

**templatetags folder**

**filename: ttags.py**

```py
from django.template import Library
import markdown2

register = Library()

@register.filter('markdown_to_html')
def markdown_to_html(markdown_text):
    htmlversion=markdown2.markdown(markdown_text)
    return htmlversion
```

**templatefile**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load ttags %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content">
{{ step.description | markdown_to_html | safe }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**The Text that was provided to be rendered was as below**

````
##### Usage of Variables

```python
name = "David"
age = 10
```

In the above example name and age are variables that store Text and Numbers respectively.

> Always remember to use Variables in your programs to store information.
````

**The HTML Code of the Rendered Output was as below**

```
<h5>Usage of Variables</h5>

<p><code>python
name = "David"
age = 10
</code></p>

<p>In the above example name and age are variables that store Text and Numbers respectively.</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>Always remember to use Variables in your programs to store information.</p>
</blockquote>
```

The Code Syntax does not display in two lines

Comment: Blockquote has been resolved. The code block does not appear in two lines.

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, please update your question with the rendered HTML code. You may need to use your borwser's "view source" or "inspect" tools to obtain the HTML.

Comment: ```<code>
name='David'
print(name)
</code>```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56260513/edit) your question and paste in the HTML rendered for the entire Markdown Input.

Comment: The question has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the [fenced code blocks](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/fenced-code-blocks) extension, which is not a standard Markdown feature. In your filter definition do this:

```py
htmlversion = markdown2.markdown(markdown_text, extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])
```

Note the addition of the `extras` keyword argument passed to `markdown2.markdown`. If you want syntax highlighting to also work you will need to have `pygments` installed and a copy of the relevant CSS files to define the highlighting styles.

I have no experience with and have never used the Markdown2 library. So how can I be sure this is correct? Note that the fenced code block:

````
```python
name = "David"
age = 10
```
````

Was getting rendered to:

```html
<p><code>python
name = "David"
age = 10
</code></p>
```

The entire contents of the fenced code block, including the language identifier are being wrapped in an inline code span (`<p><code>`), not a code block (`<pre><code>`). This suggests that the Markdown parser is interpreting the backticks as a [code span](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code), not a code block. As fenced code blocks are not part of the original [Markdown rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), we can only assume that the parser, like most, does not support fenced code blocks by default. In fact, a quick check of the [documentation](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2#extra-syntax-aka-extensions) shows that fenced code blocks need to be enabled via an extension for them to work.

Comment: if you are using **Python-Markdown** enable **fenced code blocks** with:
`markdown.markdown(some_text, extensions=['fenced_code'])`